I am facing the issue Stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command
I am automating the calculator using Python then facing an issue in executing the Python script.
issue: Stacktrace:

UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\2024913-11392-1tpj7fa.rxr2\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'.
Original error: Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object.

complete script:
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.common import AppiumOptions
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy  
import time
import os

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps["platformName"] = "Android"
desired_caps["platformVersion"] = "7.1.1"
desired_caps["deviceName"] = "Pixel 6"
desired_caps["automationName"] = "UIAutomator2"
desired_caps["appPackage"]="com.google.android.calculator"
desired_caps["appActivity"]="com.android.calculator2.calculator"
desired_caps["noReset"] = "true"
desired_caps["udid"] = "emulator-5554"
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",               options=AppiumOptions().load_capabilities(desired_caps))

def test_add_operation():
    ele_id_1_p = driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ID,"com.google.android.calculator:id/digit_6")
    #print(ele_id_1)
    ele_id_1_p.click()
    print("Clicked on 6 button")
    #time.sleep(2)
    plus = driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ID,"com.google.android.calculator:id/op_add")
    plus.click()
    print("Clicked on plus button")
    ele_id_2_p = driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ID,"com.google.android.calculator:id/digit_2")
    ele_id_2_p.click()
    print("Clicked on 2 button")
    result_p = driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ID,"com.google.android.calculator:id/eq").text

    print("Clicked on result button",result_p)
def tearDown():
    driver.quit()

test_add_operation()
time.sleep(10)
tearDown()

I am executing the script and the script should be able to be in the running state.
